# Cannot convert from int to Android.Graphics.Color

Tags: android, xamarin

In my `Resources--> Values--> colors.xml`

```
<color name="myview_background">#EDDDDD</color>
```

And I am trying to assign that color as follows:

```
 holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Resource.Color.myview_background);
```

I am getting the following error, I wonder how could I fix?

> Cannot convert from int to Android.Graphics.Color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(_activity.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.mainview_background));
```

Comment: getting the following error `Resource does not contain a definition for the GetColor`

Comment: sorry, typo: it's Resources.GetColor

Comment: getting the following error `The name Resources does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Resources is a property of Android.Activity.  Is this code in an Activity or somewhere else?

Comment: I have updated your answer and upvoted and accepted. Thanks a lot Jason, you are suberp as always.

Comment: can you get Application.Context.Resources?

Comment: This is deprecated nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `Resources.GetColor(int)` is [deprecated for Android API level 23](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29) (Marshmallow).

**Standard**

So if you want to get the color resource for an API of 23 or greater u need to additionally include the theme used to style the color attributes:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
{
    holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.mainview_background, Theme));
}
else
{
    holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.mainview_background));
}
```

**v4 Support Library**

If you are making use of the [support libraries (version 23+)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int)) you can use of `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);`

```
holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.GetColor(Resource.Color.mainview_background)));
```

Answer (score 2):

This works better for me:

```
view.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.my_color);
```

Just because I don't need to get the actual color, it also works if you want to use a image or any type of drawable:

```
view.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.my_drawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I normally do!

```
holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myview_background));
```